# How do you run an external command from a Java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, runtime.exec

I am developing a small web application that requests user input and passes that input as the command line arguments of an external program on the server side machine.

```
public class WorkflowServlet extends HttpServlet 

  public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter( "username" );
    String workflow = request.getParameter( "workflow" );
    String preInflation = request.getParamater( "preInflation" );
    String email = request.getParamater( "email" );

    try {
      executeShellCommand( "java ClusterProcess " + username + " "
                            + workflow + " " + preInflation + " " + email );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      response.sendRedirect( "WorkflowAction.jsp" ); return;
    }

      response.sendRedirect( "WorkflowInProgress.jsp" );
    }
  }


  public static void executeShellCommand( String command ) {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command.split( " " ) ).waitFor();
  }
}
```

No exceptions are thrown - it just seems to do nothing. Even if I pass in something really simple such as "touch test.txt" to executeShellCommmand it does nothing. I can successfully run the command manually via the command line.

What must I do?

Comment: also, why are you not using the returned value from waitFor? it might tell you something.

Comment: Can you post the URL where this is running? (no really, don't - you're not escaping your user inputs!!)

Comment: @Garee -- Use ProcessBuilder. it saves trouble from whitespace handling.. It may be possible that command executed in different working directory(that of webserver).. Try something like /bin/touch  /tmp/atestfile.txt

Comment: @davogotland, the split breaks the input into separate arguments. Otherwise it would be treated as a single argument when handed off to the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not capturing the input stream or error stream you are missing potential feedback from the process. I adapted the following code (outside the comfort of my IDE) from something I had written previously, so I apologize if there are obvious errors.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
...

String[] commands = {"/usr/bin/touch", "/home/blah/test.txt"};
//this could be set to a specific directory, if desired
File dir = null;
BufferedReader is = null;
BufferedReader es = null;

try
{
    Process process;
    if (dir != null)
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null, directory);
    else
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
    String line;
    is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while((line = is.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    es = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    while((line = es.readLine()) != null)
        System.err.println(line);

    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitCode == 0)
        System.out.println("It worked");
    else
        System.out.println("Something bad happend. Exit code: " + exitCode);
} //try
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Something when wrong: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} //catch
finally
{
    if (is != null)
        try { is.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
    if (os != null)
        try { es.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
} //finally
```

Comment: Your code does not solve that problem. The servlet does not redirect properly.

Comment: @artaxerxe - I am not sure what you mean. There is nothing in the original post about redirecting. Additionally, the code example I provided was to demonstrate reading the input stream and error stream. It wasn't intended to be a servlet example.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `exec()`ing something and using a shell that has all sorts of nifty things ... like a search path.

Specify the full path of the process you want to `exec()`; e.g. `/usr/bin/touch` or `/path/to/java`